# how to access *args input from parent function?

Tags: python

I have to create a function `mega_calculator`, that takes in two inputs: a function and the number of times, I should repeat it. The function should return a value when I call it. inside the parent function(mega_calculator), now I have to create a second function that takes in the same number of inputs as the parent function `mega_calculator` by giving it parameters `*args` when I create it. My question is, how do I access the parent function parameters inside the second function?

I thought that `*args` was a list of parameters and therefore if I called the first and second values, I could save the function operation and repeat amounts onto variables, to later use inside the second function, but this did not work.

What should I do for that?, any help is loved and appreciated greatly. we must have the weird function setup, so unfortunately I can't just make a nice simple while loop.

```
    def mega_calculator(fn, repeat = 1000):
        def helper(*args):
            function = *args[0]
            bob = *args[1]
            while bob > 0:
                total += function
                return (total/repeat)
        return helper()

`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood; `args` captures any arguments (not already named explicitly) passed to `helper()` but you don't pass *any* arguments to that function.

You instead call it directly with no arguments whatsoever.

You don't need to pass in arguments here however, as `fn` and `repeat` are directly accessible from the closure.

Most likely the assignment asks you to *return* `helper` and call `fn` with those arguments:

```
def mega_calculator(fn, repeat=1000):
    def helper(*args):
        total = 0
        for _ in range(repeat):
            total += fn(*args)
        return total / repeat
    return helper
```

Now `mega_calculator()` returns a new function object, that when called, passes on any arguments given on to `fn` when it calls that function.

A small demo:

```
>>> def mega_calculator(fn, repeat=1000):
...     def helper(*args):
...         total = 0
...         for _ in range(repeat):
...             total += fn(*args)
...         return total / repeat
...     return helper
... 
>>> def add(a, b):
...     return a + b
... 
>>> repeated = mega_calculator(add, 10)
>>> repeated(5, 6)
11
```

The `add()` function was called 10 times, but because the helper also *divides* the resulting sum by the number of repetitions, it's still 11 that is returned.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked! sad thing is we tried separate pieces of it, but i guess we had to make all those changes together. i will choose this as the solution as soon as the time is up